# Can I show a map Legend in MKMapView that is parsed from a google map KML file

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am currently using KML files that are generated from google maps. The KML's that have complex polygones have a Legend as well. I would like to display the Legend. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using the current IOS Map api's

Comment: Do you want the legend to always appear at a fixed position on the screen, so that it does not move when the user pans/zooms the map? Or do you want the legend to be located at a specific coordinate position and thus move around as the user moves the map?

Comment: I would like the legend to appear in a fixed position.

Comment: @mattwallace: How did you do this finally?